# Firebase "admin user" in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

Here's what I want to achieve:

I have an iOS frontend, a Vapor backend, and a Firebase storage bucket. I have an app where a small portion of the functionality is being able to add images to some Note objects. When the user attaches an image to a Note, I want to upload the image to the bucket, get the key/url where it's stored, and store that in the backend DB. All that is simple enough, except - I want the bucket to be accessible ONLY by my iOS code and my backend code, so not just publicly accessible by anyone.

The backend is covered via the service account stuff. but I'm not sure about how to cover the iOS side. Firebase generated this basic rule to prevent public access:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I believe this rule allows only Firebase-authenticated users to use the bucket, but I do not plan to authenticate my users through Firebase. Is there a way I can set up rules such that the bucket is only accessible via my own iOS code? Should I essentially just create a single Firebase user, and have the app authenticate as that user on every app launch? Can I configure Firebase such that it uses some secret that allows it to perform storage operations that get past the rules?

**edited for clarity

Comment: Look up Firebase anonymous authorization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jnpdx commented, have a look at Firebase's [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth), which allows you to sign in (and identify) users without asking for credentials. Based on that you'll then want to ensure that each user can only read the files they're authorized for.

While `if request.auth != null` may seem good for that initially, I find it's often better to start with the principle of least privilege - and for example [have some form of content ownership based access rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#content-owner_only_access).

Finally, also have a look at Firebase [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) which was introduced earlier this year, and works together with the attestation providers on your phone to reduce the risk of unauthorized code being used to call the Storage APIs.